# Is it possible to check if a subArea contains blocks in Concrete5?

Tags: php, concrete5

Is there a way to check if a subArea contains blocks before outputting markup when using the Area Splitter add-on?

Have been trying stuff like this but don't understand how to make it work sorry:

```
<?php
  defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die("Access Denied.");
  $c = Page::getCurrentPage();
  $this->controller->setArea($this->area);
?>

<div class="box">
  <? if (($this->controller->subArea()->getTotalBlocksInArea($c) != 0) || ($c->isEditMode())) : ?>
  <div class="box-header">
    <?php $this->controller->subArea(); ?>
  </div>
  <? endif; ?>

  <? if (($this->controller->subArea()->getTotalBlocksInArea($c) != 0) || ($c->isEditMode())) : ?>
  <div class="box-footer">
    <?php $this->controller->subArea(); ?>
  </div>
  <? endif; ?>
</div>
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the "area splitter" addon... I believe that's a really old thing that has been supplanted by the native "Area Layouts" in the core (which were added way back in 5.4 I believe).

If you're talking about the native "area layouts" functionality, though, then I have some code in the free [Page List Teasers addon](http://www.concrete5.org/marketplace/addons/page-list-teasers) that does this:

```
$aHandle = 'Main'; //<--CHANGE THIS ACCORDINGLY
$c = Page::getCurrentPage();

//Get blocks inside "Area Layouts"...
$layout_blocks = array();
$area = new Area($aHandle);
$layouts = $area->getAreaLayouts($c); //returns empty array if no layouts
foreach ($layouts as $layout) {
    $maxCell = $layout->getMaxCellNumber();
    for ($i=1; $i<=$maxCell; $i++) {
        $cellAreaHandle = $layout->getCellAreaHandle($i);
        $cellBlocks = $c->getBlocks($cellAreaHandle);
        $layout_blocks = array_merge($layout_blocks, $cellBlocks);
    }
}

//Get non-area-layout blocks...
$nonlayout_blocks = $c->getBlocks($aHandle); //Returns blocks in the order they're on the page

//Combine the two sets of blocks
$blocks = array_merge($layout_blocks, $nonlayout_blocks);
```

Hopefully you can take that code and modify it to achieve what you want (e.g calling `count()` on the layout_blocks array or the combined array, depending on which you want).